# Create navigation through taxonomy

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, navigation

We have an taxonomy with "news" and "articles" parent terms and structure with different child terms.

What we need, is simple navigation through this taxonomy **without menus**, but with pages: so at the "Article" page are presented child terms of "Article", once an term is selected user is redirected to the page with child terms of this term **and** list of items in current term + path to this term (like Articles > Child term 1 > Child term 2 etc for easier navigation).

Such navigation system is typical for many CMSs, but I couldn't find nothing like this in Drupal 7.

Is there a module or guide to implement such navigation?

Comment: I'm trying to understand exactly what you want to achieve but is not clear for me. Can you elaborate more your question woith a detailed example?

Comment: Let's say we have an "Articles" in the navigation menu. It links to a page (node) where in the main region are presented both taxonomy terms of "Articles" (as links) and (below) content of currently selected term. So when I click to any term I'm redirected to another page with the same links but another content (of the term I selected). The current term in term list is marked with bold or in other way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way we found to do this:

1. [Use Taxonomy menu block](https://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_menu_block) module to create multiple blocks based on taxonomy. Not Taxonomy menu module since it doesn't allow to create multiple blocks per one vocabulary.
2. Set Pathauto to generate taxonomy pages by the template [term:root:url:path]/[term:name], where "url:path" is the alias manually entered for every parent term.
3. Override taxonomy pages with views.
4. Show Taxonomy menu blocks in main region of pages filtered by taxonomy pages url:path aliases.
5. Some CSS to place the blocks in right place.

This method is good enough, however it doesn't allow any connection between Taxonomy menu block and the content: feature we really need. For example, it's impossible to mark with bold the item in Taxonomy menu block displayed at this moment. We plan to rewrite the whole taxonomy pages template with our own php code to implement the menu and additional conditions of the currrently displayed content (may be with ajax) in future.

Thanks for no good answer.

Answer (score 2):

[Taxonomy menu](https://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_menu) module suits your need.

> Transforms your taxonomy vocabularies into menus with ease!

Comment: Not exactly. Taxonomy menu provides menu, but it doesn't provide navigation itself - just links to term pages with teasers, does it? We need a way to tie the links with content displayed on the page, so it wouldn't provide just a link to term page, but node with both links (implemented right into main area, not in menu anywhere in the layout) and the content.